# How to save a view of a folder

Tags: c++, shell, winapi, view, explorer

Let's say you'd like to give the user the ability to save (and name) the current view state of an Explorer folder, and then selectively apply that view state to other folders if he or she chooses (perhaps using the right-click menu).

So far I've come across `SHGetViewStatePropertyBag`, `IPropertyBag`, and `IPersistPropertyBag`, which look promising.  But there's apparently also `IShellView::SaveViewState` and `IShellBrowser::GetViewStateStream`.  I'm not sure which APIs are appropriate for this task. Any thoughts?

Also,  how should things be saved--in a registry key, or local app data, or something else?

I appreciate any guidance.  Thank you very much.

Comment: That looks like a lot of questions rolled into one.

Comment: In theory, you should use GetViewStateStream to get the state as a stream to be able to read/write it. But you can only call it at specific times (see doc). Also nothing says the state is not specific per folder and can be applied elsewhere. It's probably easier to store information by yourself. SHGetViewStatePropertyBag is one deprecated impl of IPropertyBag in the registry (in fact, maybe the Shell implementation does still use it, but that's not really our concern I believe).

Comment: [IShellView::SaveViewState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellview-saveviewstate) is for this purpose and Windows Explorer [store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellbrowser-getviewstatestream#notes-to-implementers) view on a per-user basis in the registry.